# How to display only names of the file

Tags: linux, services, etc

How to display only the names of the last 10 services listed in /etc/services?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Seems like assignment/quiz questions :P

Comment: As the down-arrow hint says: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: The title doesn't make a lot of sense compared with the body; could you clarify what you're after, here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -n 10 /etc/services | cut -f 1 -d " "
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way:

`awk -F' ' 'NF=1' /etc/services |tail -n 10`

or

`awk -F' ' '{print $1}' /etc/services |tail -n 10`

Answer (score -2):

You can use following command.

```
ls -ltr | tail
```